# Column widths are not equal

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \caption{Bobot kriteria}
        \label{tabel6}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Kriteria&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Pembuat keputusan ($D_1 - D_4$)}&Nilai rata-rata\\
            \hline
            $C_1$&AI&AI&AI&AI&$([0.8, 0.9], [0, 0.1])$\\
            \hline
            $C_2$&VI&VI&VI&I&$([0.659,0.762], [0.132,0.238])$\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why the width of the 5th column not same as the width of 2nd, 3rd, and 4th columns? How to fix it?

Comment: Because the contents of the `\multirow{4}{…}` above is too wide for thlengths of the 4 corresponding columns. I suggest to use a two-line multicolumn with the `makecell` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a `\multicolumn` object is wider than the combined natural widths of the spanned columns, the excess space goes in the last spanned column.

If you cannot split the wide `\multicolumn` entry across lines, you can measure it and set the width of the columns to a fourth of this width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newlength{\spannedlength}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
  \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\abovecaptionskip}%
  \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering

\caption{Bobot kriteria}
\label{tabel6}

\settowidth{\spannedlength}{Pembuat keputusan ($D_1$ -- $D_4$}
% this will span four columns, six \tabcolsep spaces, but
% we need to take care of four \arrayrulewidth wide rules
\setlength{\spannedlength}{\dimexpr(\spannedlength-6\tabcolsep+4\arrayrulewidth)/4}

\begin{tabular}{|c|*{4}{w{c}{\spannedlength}|}c|}
\hline
Kriteria & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Pembuat keputusan ($D_1$ -- $D_4$)} & Nilai rata-rata\\
\hline
$C_1$ & AI & AI & AI & AI & $([0.8, 0.9], [0, 0.1])$\\
\hline
$C_2$ & VI & VI & VI & I  & $([0.659,0.762], [0.132,0.238])$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have changed `$D_1-D_2$` into `$D_1$ -- $D_2$` as it doesn't seem a subtraction.
I also suggested how to get a proper distance between the caption and the table.

[image]

A different realization of the table with `booktabs` and no vertical rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\newlength{\spannedlength}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
  \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\abovecaptionskip}%
  \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering

\caption{Bobot kriteria}
\label{tabel6}

\settowidth{\spannedlength}{Pembuat keputusan ($D_1$ -- $D_4$}
% this will span four columns and six \tabcolsep spaces
\setlength{\spannedlength}{\dimexpr(\spannedlength-6\tabcolsep)/4}

\begin{tabular}{@{} c *{4}{w{c}{\spannedlength}} c @{}}
\toprule
Kriteria & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Pembuat keputusan ($D_1$ -- $D_4$)} & Nilai rata-rata\\
\midrule
$C_1$ & AI & AI & AI & AI & $([0.8, 0.9], [0, 0.1])$\\
$C_2$ & VI & VI & VI & I  & $([0.659,0.762], [0.132,0.238])$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you place `($D_1 - D_4$)` on a row by itself, directly below `Pembuat keputusan`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \addtolength\tabcolsep{2pt}
        \centering
        \caption{Bobot kriteria\strut}
        \label{tabel6}
        \begin{tabular}{ | *{6}{c|} }
            \hline
            Kriteria & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Pembuat keputusan} & Nilai rata-rata \\
                     & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{($D_1 - D_4$)} &  \\
            \hline
            $C_1$ & AI & AI & AI & AI & ($[0.8, 0.9]$, $[0, 0.1]$)\\
            \hline
            $C_2$ & VI & VI & VI & I & ($[0.659,0.762]$, $[0.132,0.238]$)\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix by hand the width of the columns 2, 3, 4 and 5.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Bobot kriteria}
    \label{tabel6}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|*{4}{w{c}{1cm}|}c|}
        \hline
        Kriteria&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Pembuat keputusan ($D_1 - D_4$)}&Nilai rata-rata\\
        \hline
        $C_1$&AI&AI&AI&AI&$([0.8, 0.9], [0, 0.1])$\\
        \hline
        $C_2$&VI&VI&VI&I&$([0.659,0.762], [0.132,0.238])$\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output fo the above code]